# Material3 - How to access the hex color values?

Tags: android, material3, material-you

I recently updated my Android Studio version to the newest one (giraffe) and I noticed the `themes.xml` is now changed and does not give you the colors (teal and purple) like it would in previous versions.

[image]

But once I ran the newly created app, I noticed the status bar has a purple color.

[image]

How can I access the colors in this theme? And how can I get the exact hex colors used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I was only able to override theme in the **themes.xml** using somethings like:

```
<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
<!-- Status bar color. -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor" >?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
```

And my in **colors.xml** I had

```
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#1F2326</color>
```

I have also tried locating the Material3 **colors.xml** and **values.xml** and I found them under

```
..\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\caches\transforms-3\3b89e20d8303563adc73b801dcf3de9c\transformed\material-1.9.0\res\values
```